# How do I prompt a user for password when uninstalling an application or make the app uninstallable?

Tags: c#, windows

I have developed a windows application in Visual Studio 2015.  During installation I register a user password that is stored in a database. I would like to require the password to uninstall.

Is it possible to prompt a user for a password during an uninstall?

My biggest challenge is to protect my application from being uninstall without password and or to uninstall at all.

Comment: Fist time your app runs change the uninstaller path created by your installer to point to your app with a specific command line, do your thing when you detect this then execute the original uninstaller.   Of course I could delete your exe manually at any time ...

Comment: Thanks  @AlexK. i'm working on , will let you know . thanks

Comment: Hai all, i have manage to protect my app from being uninstalled from control panel, i'm not sure if u use the right approach by modifying regedit for my application. it solve my problem anyway.

Comment: RegistryKey key = null;
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{63EF3DE1-F37C-4B1B-BBBD-26910690C7CF}", true);


                key.DeleteValue("ModifyPath", true);
                key.DeleteValue("UnInstallString", true);
                key.DeleteValue("Version", true);
                key.DeleteValue("VersionMajor", true);
                key.DeleteValue("VersionMinor", true);
                key.DeleteValue("WindowsInstaller", true);

                key.Close();

Comment: If the user is an administrator on the machine, they'll always be able to uninstall the software, whether via the official installer or by manually removing entries in the file system, registry, etc. Unless the software you're developing is intended to be a rootkit, I'd suggest giving up on this requirement. If the user isn't an administrator, they shouldn't be able to remove the software anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works from me. Application not showing in the control panel. Thank you [Siyabonga Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393225/siyabonga-gregory)
`RegistryKey key = null; key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{63EF3DE1-F37C-4B1B-BBBD-26910690C7CF}", true); key.DeleteValue("ModifyPath", true); key.DeleteValue("UnInstallString", true); key.DeleteValue("Version", true); key.DeleteValue("VersionMajor", true); key.DeleteValue("VersionMinor", true); key.DeleteValue("WindowsInstaller", true); key.Close();`

Comment: My pleasure @tony-walter